# Block Diagram of a switch

Tags: pstricks, pst-sigsys

I'm trying to draw a switch schemabloc, using [`pst-sigsys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-sigsys)...

The thing is, with the `\ncstar` macro it's only possible to "merge" multiple inputs into 1, and not the opposite...

I've managed to do this, but it's a mess with the arrows (and with the option `style=Arrow` in general)...

1. Has any body a trick to set the arrows right ?
2. If I `\input` this drawing in a document, the `\psset{style=Arrow}` will conflict with other things in my document, and the size of the arrows will be different (when created with `Arrow` or the classical PSTricks option). Any ideas ?

Here's the MWE I use :

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add, pst-eucl}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](-5, -2.5)(3.5, 6)
    \psset{style = RoundCorners}%, arrowinset=0}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](-3.5, 1.75){SW}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering Type}}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](0.25, 4.25){C1}{Case 1}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](0.25, 1.75){C2}{Case 2}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](0.25, -0.75){C3}{Case 3}

    \psset{style = Arrow}   
    \nclist{->}{ncline}{SW, C2}
    \ncdiagg[angleA=180, arm =.5]{C1}{SW}
    \ncdiagg[angleA=180, angleB=180]{C3}{SW}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And the result of this code :

[image: MWE result]

Comment: What is the mess with `style=Arrow`? Could you post a minimal example of such a mess? And what is the `\ncstar` macro? I never met it.

Comment: `\ncstar` is defined on page 22 of the [doc](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-sigsys/pst-sigsys-doc.pdf)... I solved the `arrow` problem, I just had to declare `style=Arrow` as an option of the `\pspicture`. Thanks anyway !

Comment: What do ou mean with ‘setting the arrows right’?

Comment: I anwsered my question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271747/28926)... The aim was to have all the arrows going from the switch to the cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Herbert pointed, the problem can be easily solved by inverting the `{->}` in the `\psdiagg` command.

It gives this : [image: MWE Result]

And the code is here :

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add, pst-eucl}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](-5, -2.5)(3.5, 6)
    \psset{style = RoundCorners, style = Arrow}%, arrowinset=0}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](-3.5, 1.75){SW}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering Type}}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](0.25, 3.5){C1}{Case 1}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](0.25, 1.75){C2}{Case 2}
    \psfblock[gratioWh=2](0.25, 0){C3}{Case 3}

    \nclist{->}{ncline}{SW, C2}
    \ncdiagg[angleA=180, arm =.75]{<-}{C1}{SW}   % Add {<-} here
    \ncdiagg[angleA=180, arm =.75]{<-}{C3}{SW}   % idem

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

PS : I anwsered my own question, because the problem was only with the arrows, and I didn't hee how the `psmatrix` solved it. But all the credit belong to Herbert.

Comment: it makes no real sense to use pst-sigsys for such simple node diagrams.

Comment: I agree (the doc is crappy), but I found this and got used to...  What would you recommand instead ? `pst-node` ?

Answer (score 4):

A solution with the `psmatrix` environment

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\PBox#1{\psframebox{\parbox[c][1cm][c]{2cm}{\centering#1}}}
\psset{framearc=0.1,arrowscale=1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=2,rowsep=0.8]
                      &  [name=C1]\PBox{Case 1} \\
[name=SW]\PBox{Type}  &  [name=C2]\PBox{Case 2} \\
                      &  [name=C3]\PBox{Case 1} 
\end{psmatrix}  
\ncline{->}{SW}{C2}
\ncdiagg[angleA=180, arm=.5]{->}{C1}{SW}
\ncdiagg[angleA=180, arm=.5]{->}{C3}{SW}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I haven't clearly explained my problem. I want all the arrows going from the `Type` to the other boxes.

Comment: then change the order of the nodes (e.g. `{C1}{SW}` into `{SW}{C1}` ) or `->` into `<-`. That's all ...